# Using enumerate for a list of lists (json)

Tags: python, dictionary, while-loop, spotify, enumerate

I'm looking at Spotify music with python. Haven't been able to find an answer online so far. I'd like to get information from each song retrieved from the API (2000 songs). I've got the artist of every song, which is a long string of json seen below:

```
print(artist):

#This is the output:

[[{'track': {'album': {'artists': [{'external_urls': {'spotify': 'https://open.spotify.com/artist/1uiEZYehlNivdK3iQyAbye'},
       'href': 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/1uiEZYehlNivdK3iQyAbye',
       'id': '1uiEZYehlNivdK3iQyAbye',
       'name': 'Tom Misch',
       'type': 'artist',
       'uri': 'spotify:artist:1uiEZYehlNivdK3iQyAbye'},
      {'external_urls': {'spotify': 'https://open.spotify.com/artist/2rspptKP0lPBdlJJAJHqht'},
       'href': 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/2rspptKP0lPBdlJJAJHqht',
       'id': '2rspptKP0lPBdlJJAJHqht',
       'name': 'Yussef Dayes',
       'type': 'artist',
       'uri': 'spotify:artist:2rspptKP0lPBdlJJAJHqht'}]}}}, 

# and so on
```

Since the *artist* variable is a list of lists & dictionaries, when I print the length of *artist* I get 20:

```
len(artist)
20
```

However, within each element of the *artist* variable, there are 100 items:

```
len(artist[0])
100
```

I want to loop through all 2000 items in *artist*, and add them to one list. So far my code has been very clunky:

```
artist_list = []
i=0
while i<100:

        artist_list.append(artist[0][i]["track"]["album"]["artists"][0]["name"])
        artist_list.append(artist[1][i]["track"]["album"]["artists"][0]["name"])
        artist_list.append(artist[2][i]["track"]["album"]["artists"][0]["name"])
        artist_list.append(artist[3][i]["track"]["album"]["artists"][0]["name"])
        artist_list.append(artist[4][i]["track"]["album"]["artists"][0]["name"])
        artist_list.append(artist[5][i]["track"]["album"]["artists"][0]["name"])
        artist_list.append(artist[6][i]["track"]["album"]["artists"][0]["name"])
        artist_list.append(artist[7][i]["track"]["album"]["artists"][0]["name"])
        artist_list.append(artist[8][i]["track"]["album"]["artists"][0]["name"])
        artist_list.append(artist[9][i]["track"]["album"]["artists"][0]["name"])
        artist_list.append(artist[10][i]["track"]["album"]["artists"][0]["name"])
        artist_list.append(artist[11][i]["track"]["album"]["artists"][0]["name"])
        artist_list.append(artist[12][i]["track"]["album"]["artists"][0]["name"])
        artist_list.append(artist[13][i]["track"]["album"]["artists"][0]["name"])
        artist_list.append(artist[14][i]["track"]["album"]["artists"][0]["name"])
        artist_list.append(artist[15][i]["track"]["album"]["artists"][0]["name"])
        artist_list.append(artist[16][i]["track"]["album"]["artists"][0]["name"])
        artist_list.append(artist[17][i]["track"]["album"]["artists"][0]["name"])

        i+=1
```

What's the best way to shorten this? I've tried using *enumerate* but couldn't quite figure how to do it. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Please provide a real example of an artist with at least 2 songs so we can test the code.

Comment: A list is not `JSON`. `JSON` is a language-independent, **string** representation of some data which first needs to be parsed before it can become, in your case, a list. But once it is parsed, you are no longer dealing with `JSON` and we don't need to know what its genesis was.

Comment: In the Spotify API documentation, it mentions that every output is in JSON format.

Comment: Yes, and then it is sent down to you and whatever software you are using to retrieve it, for example the `requests` or `urllib3` packages, is then parsing it into a list of dictionaries. Somebody using Java might be parsing it into an `ArrayList` of `Map` objects (or whatever). The only point I am making is what you are showing us is no longer a `JSON` string and that the fact that this Python object originally came from a `JSON` string is not particularly relevant. Somebody seeing the `json` tag might think you have  a `JSON`-related problem, but you don't. You have a `dict` problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using a double for loop:

```py
artist_list = []
for a in artist:
    for b in a:
        artist_list.append(b["track"]["album"]["artists"][0]["name"])
```

However, it's more pythonic (and efficient) to use a python list comprehension:

```py
artist_list = [b["track"]["album"]["artists"][0]["name"] for a in artist for b in a]
```